# A simple python loop issue

Tags: python, loops

This code:

```
import random
print("\tWelcome to the guess my number program\n")

print("im thinking of a number between 1 and 100")
print("try to guess it in 5 attempts\n")

randomNum = random.randint(1,101)

tries = 0

userNumber = int(input("please pick a number"))

while userNumber != randomNum:
    if userNumber > randomNum:
        print ("lower") 
    else:
        print("higher") 
    tries += 1

print ("you guessed it! the number was" , randomNum)
```

For some reason this produces an infinite loop. Any help, im still getting used to python.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves a downvote. The title is explanatory enough and although the OP is making an elementary mistake, we all did the same when we started.

Comment: i'm finding it hard to tell whether the indentation used within the while loop is on purpose or copy+paste formatting error or just a programmatic mistake.

Comment: @Relfor The code wouldn't run if OP had actually written his code that way. Can't have an infinite loop if you have an `IndentationError`. :)

Comment: Besides the answer you got, also keep in mind that you prompt the user to try and guess in 5 attempts, and keep a counter of the number of `tries`, but you apparently forgot to do anything with it - like preventing more than 5 tries or at least printing back how many guesses it took the user.

Answer (score 5):

You never updated your `userNumber` or `randomNum` inside the while loop. So once the loop condition is met, it will execute infinitely.

You need to update your while loop as:

```
while userNumber != randomNum:
    if userNumber > randomNum:
        print ("lower") 
    else:
        print("higher") 

    tries += 1    
    userNumber = int(input("please pick a number"))
```

Comment: so the tries and userNumber are still in the loop itself? Also i have to ask for the userNumber twice in order for this too work? I actually wrote a similar program in java but i dont remember how i did it.

Comment: Yes, they both should be inside the loop only. And if you just want the give user two chance, then add the `tries` in the while loop condition.

Answer (score 3):

You've forgotten to ask the user to guess again. Try this!

```
while userNumber != randomNum:
    if userNumber > randomNum:
        print("lower")
    else:
        print("higher")
    tries += 1
    userNumber = int(input("please pick a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
import random
print("Welcome to the guess my number program!")
randomnum = random.randint(1, 100)
print("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100.")
print("Try to guess it in 5 attempts.")
tries = 0
usernumber = 0
while not usernumber == randomnum:
   usernumber = int(raw_input("please pick a number.")
   if usernumber > randomnum:
      print("Too High")
   if usernumber < randomnum:
      print("Too Low")
   tries = tries + 1
if usernumber == randomnum:
   print("You got the number!")
print("It took you " + str(tries) + " attempts.")
```